# TypeMismatchException when creating a google visualization datatable with Date type column

Tags: java, jsp, date, datatable, google-visualization

Ok, so after trying really hard for some days i am still not able to make this work.

This is the problem: I have a JSP which hosts a Google chart that is going to be constructed from data that is going to be sent through a Servlet. I'm using the Google Visualization Java libraries to implement this servlet.

Then i have this helper function that, taking some data stored in a list of objects, constructs a datatable. Following is the class that implements said function:

```
    public class DataTableGenerator {

    public static DataTable generateDatatable(List<AccesoUrl> accesos) {

        DataTable data = new DataTable();

        ArrayList<ColumnDescription> cd = new ArrayList<>();
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("fecha", ValueType.DATE, "Fecha"));
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("navegador", ValueType.TEXT, "Navegador"));
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("ip", ValueType.TEXT, "IP"));
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("os", ValueType.TEXT, "Sistema Operativo"));

        data.addColumns(cd);


        try {

            for(AccesoUrl acceso : accesos) {
                GregorianCalendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar();
                calendario.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));                

                data.addRowFromValues(calendario, acceso.getNavegador(), acceso.getIp(), acceso.getSistemaoperativo());

            }

        } catch (TypeMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Now, this piece of code should work, but instead i am getting this exception on my web server:

com.google.visualization.datasource.base.TypeMismatchException: Value type mismatch.
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.datatable.value.ValueType.createValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.datatable.DataTable.addRowFromValues(Unknown Source)

I'm at wit's end now. I have tried every variation i could find on Google so that my JSP displays this data on a Google Table type of chart. I have tried sending a date as a string, a date as a string formatted as a javascript date (i.e "Date(2015,4,4)" or "new Date(2015,4,4)"). I have tried using the DateValue object that comes with the java visualization library to construct the date as well (i.e new DateValue(2015,4,4)). I have also tried passing a Java Date as well. Nothing works, everything throws a TypeMismatchException.

I am sure it's the date that's giving me trouble because as soon as i remove the date column from the datatable everything runs fine with no exception and i can get my data displayed on the Google chart table.

So can anybody please tell me what exactly do i have to do in my Java code to be able to construct a datatable with a date cell?

Comment: Have you tried the "java.util.Date object + ValueType.DATETIME" combination? Instead of ValueType.DATE I mean.

Comment: @GergelyBacso yes, i forgot to mention it but ValueType.DATETIME is also giving me trouble. I have already tried what you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Even  I faced same issue. But it seems addRowFromValues() doesn't support DateValue(). I siwtched to addRow(TableRow). Didnt see any error's.
You can use something like below,
Sample Code:

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();
ArrayList<ColumnDescription> cd = new ArrayList<ColumnDescription>();
cd.add(new ColumnDescription("date", ValueType.DATE, "Executed Date"));
cd.add(new ColumnDescription("value", ValueType.NUMBER, "Duration "));
data.addColumns(cd);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(); 
tr.addCell(new DateValue(2015,7,7));
data.addRow(tr);
```